# PyImport_Import fails (returns NULL)

Tags: python, c

I am a newbie in python, so may be this is a silly question. I want to write simple c program with embedded python script. I have two files:

call-function.c:

```
    #include <Python.h>
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc, *pValue;

        if (argc < 3)
        {
            printf("Usage: exe_name python_source function_name\n");
            return 1;
            }

        // Initialize the Python Interpreter
        Py_Initialize();

        // Build the name object
        if ((pName = PyString_FromString(argv[1])) == NULL) {
            printf("Error: PyString_FromString\n");
            return -1;
        }

        // Load the module object
        if ((pModule = PyImport_Import(pName)) == NULL) {
            printf("Error: PyImport_Import\n");
            return -1;
        }

        // pDict is a borrowed reference 
        if ((pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule))==NULL) {
            printf("Error: PyModule_GetDict\n");
            return -1;
        }
...
```

and

hello.py:

```
def hello():
    print ("Hello, World!")
```

I compile and run this as follows:

```
gcc -g -o call-function call-function.c -I/usr/include/python2.6 -lpython2.6
./call-function hello.py hello
```

and have this:

```
Error: PyImport_Import
```

i.e. PyImport_Import returns `NULL`. Could you help me with this issue? Any help will be appreciated.

Best wishes,

Alex

Comment: you forgot the step where you draw a pentagon in chicken blood and light the black candles :P .... thats what usually works for me when mixing C and Python

Comment: Looks like `argv[0]` will be the exe name, `argv[1]` will be `hello.py`, and `argv[2]` will be `hello`. Do you want to import something else instead of `argv[1]`? You need the module name not the source file name right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. But I thought that module name is the same as file name. Is it correct?

Comment: The module name is `hello`. It's the same for standard python scripts. You couldn't run `python -c "import hello.py"` from the local directory either.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by setting PYTHONPATH to `pwd`. Also module name (without .py) should be set for argv[1].

Thank you!

Comment: Saved me tons of trouble! You're awesome for self-answering this. +1

Comment: This worked for me too! Unbelievable and completely un-intuitive considering py.exe and python.exe require the full name of the script. Thank you!!

Comment: Thank you!  Wow - spent all evening on this. Thank you thank you thank you.

Comment: Thankyou so much. But why we need to set PYTHONPATH to pwd???

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this issue also after struggling for a while.After searching the web I found that is was a system path issue.  After adding the two lines after Py_Initialize(); it worked.

OS: Windows 7, Compiler: Embarcadero C++ Builder XE6, Python: Version 2.7

Reference: [C++ With Python](https://sites.google.com/site/janezpodhostnik/programming/c-with-python)

```
Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\"C:\\Python27\")");
```

Comment: I am having the same problem and added the 2 lines you recommend, changing the path.append to "c:\python35" where my python libs and DLLs exist but it  didn't help me.  PyImport_Import() always returns NULL.

Comment: I tried Alexander's solution with and without your recommendation and it didn't seem to make a difference. However, I'm keeping it in just in case. ;-)

Comment: Works well on Linux too.

Answer (score 4):

If the python source file is located in the working directory (i.e. where the *.cpp files of the project reside), you can use...

```
PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(os.getcwd())");
```

...to add the working directory to the Python path.

Comment: you forgot  PyRun_SimpleString("import os");

Comment: and don't forget to import sys :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an obscure case but my python function was importing code that required argv to be set.  In order to fix that I had to add:

```
PySys_SetArgv(argc, argv);
```

after the Py_Initialize() call and it started working.