# PyImport_Import fails - Returns NULL

Tags: python, c++, c

First off, yes I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532371/pyimport-import-fails-returns-null) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737291/pyimport-import-returns-null), however they didn't resolve my problem/error.

---

So, I'm trying to call a Python function from C/C++, but when `PyImport_Import()` is called it returns `NULL`.

Code:

```
PyObject* fname = PyBytes_FromString("hello");
PyObject* module = PyImport_Import(fname);
```

Where `hello` is my `hello.py` file in the same directory as the executable. I have no idea where my error is, could some please point me to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thought that `PyBytes_FromString` was the the 3.x alternative of `PyString_From`.

I was wrong. `PyUnicode_FromString` is the correct alternative.

<sub>(Thanks to @wakjah for given me the tip of using error handling)</sub>

Answer (score 14):

Without knowing a whole bunch of information about how your system is set up and the contents of the Python files involved, it's difficult to diagnose your problem. Far better to let the Python runtime tell you what is wrong.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/import.html) states

> PyObject* PyImport_ImportModule(const char *name)
>
> ...
>
> Return a new reference to the imported module, or NULL ***with an exception set on failure***

(emphasis mine)

The [exception handling documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/exceptions.html) states that you can call `PyErr_Print()` to print the current exception to stderr.

So to put this into practice:

```
PyObject* fname = PyBytes_FromString("hello");
PyObject* module = PyImport_Import(fname);
if (module == nullptr)
{
    PyErr_Print();
    std::exit(1);
}
```

This will at least get you started on figuring out the error.

For future convenience, you probably want to create your own C++ exception class to wrap Python errors (and to avoid peppering your code with things like calls to `exit`).

Comment: Thanks! Turns out `PyBytes_FromString()` isn't the 3.x alternative of `PyString_FromString()`. The error I get is that `PyImport_Import()` doesn't take bytes, but strings.  `PyUnicode_FromString()` solves this issue. Thanks again! ;)

Comment: Using PyErr_Print() helped me to figure out what the issue was.