# PyImport_ImportModule always return NULL even though system path is set

Tags: python, c++, embedding

I am trying to write a simple C/C++ program in Ubuntu 17.10 to call python function using [embedding](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html). However, it always complained that it is unable to import the module using `PyImport_ImportModule`.

I have included `Python.h` in the cpp file and compile it like this:

```
g++ -L/usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu/ -g -o main main.cpp -I/usr/include/python3.6 -lpython3.6
```

I have tried the following things but none of the approach works:

1. add the current path to `path` using `PySys_GetObject` and `PyList_Insert` (as per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137145/python-c-api-pyimport-importmodule-fail-when-the-file-has-an-import-statement))
2. set `PYTHONPATH=/tmp` then run the main program (as per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532371/pyimport-import-fails-returns-null))

/tmp/main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <python3.6/Python.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject* sysPath = PySys_GetObject("path");
    PyObject *path = PyBytes_FromString("/tmp");
    int result = PyList_Append(sysPath, path);

    PyObject* module = PyImport_ImportModule("hello");

    if (0 != module)
    {
        PyObject* helloFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(module, "hello");
        if (helloFunc)
        {
            PyEval_CallObject(helloFunc, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "hello function is NULL");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "hello module is NULL -- somehow");
    }

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

/tmp/hello.py

```
class hello(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Hello world: init")

    def hello(self):
        print("Hello world: hello")
```

Please can someone tell me why `PyImport_ImportModule` always return NULL in my simple program?

Many thanks!

Comment: Does the account this program is running as actually have permission to read `/tmp/hello.py`?

Comment: Yes I have set it to 777 and it does not work.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, were you able to fix it?